# Is it possible to specify which field to use for data relation in Bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

Im currently having an issue where i want to specify to the bookshelf model which field to use to make the data relation.

it seems to always use the id (primary key) of the model table; as far as i've found out it's only possible to set column for the relation but not which to use from model.

for example:

```
var StopsWithCustomer = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'stops',
    customers: function () {
        return this.hasOne(customerWithStop, 'id');
    }
});
```

it has to match on customerWithStop on the column id but it has to use the column customer_id from 'stops' to make this relation; is there any way to specify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides `tableName` Bookshelf.js also provides an `idAttribute` property. That will allow you to override Bookshelf.js' `id` default.

Note the second argument of the relationship (like your `hasOne()`) is the foreign key, not the target's primary key.

Example:

```
var Language = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'languages', 
  idAttribute: 'languageid'
});
var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'posts', 
  idAttribute: 'postid', 
  Language: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Language,'languageid');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks bud; that was exactly what i was looking for :) Fixed it with a raw query up till now but figured there had to be an option to do this.